# Python launcher not working at all in mac

Tags: python, macos, tkinter

It was doing just fine, and then suddenly when I tried to run my tkinter program, the program didn't open and instead the python launcher rocket kept bouncing up and down in my dock doing nothing. My program doesn't seem to be the problem because other tkinter programs I made previously do not open as well as the one I'm working on right now.

I've searched up on the internet but I couldn't find any answers to my situation. Please help me get my program running. Thank you

Comment: The common thing to do is reinstall Python when this happens.

Comment: How are you running the code? What happens if you open a terminal window and type `python /path/to/your/script.py`? Often, this type of behavior is the result of mixing `pack` and `grid` for widgets that have the same parent.